# htaccess 301 redirect whilst keeping original address

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I need the URL www.domain.com to 301 redirect to sub.domain.com.

Is this possible whilst keeping the www.domain.com in the address bar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to keep www.domain.com in the address bar, then it's not redirecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called url rewriting. You can find a tutorial here: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/
The following code rewrites www.domain.com to www.domain.com/subfolder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Comment: please, let us know if this answer solved your question. If so, please mark the question as 'solved', so help you others !

Comment: Sorry, been away hence the lack of activity on my part! Will be looking at this tomorrow evening.

Comment: Hi Dave, so looked at the link you sent. Am I along the right lines with the below?  Anything to www points to sub but the address bar remains as www?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain\.com [NC]

Comment: Your code will redirect the browser, not rewrite. Redirecting changes the addressbar, rewriting doesn't ! Rewriting happens on the server, redirecting happens on the client (which will see the change). A 301 redirect must be used to tell the browser that a page has been moved permanently; while a rewrite must be used to guide the user to another page, without him knowing. So with your code, the user's address bar will change.